# How does the operating system know to send a signal to the following program?

Tags: c, linux

The program uses the alarm system call as follows

```
alarm(120);
```

However I don't understand at a low-level how the operating system sends a signal after 120 seconds?

Comment: From `man 2 alarm` *"alarm() arranges for a SIGALRM signal to be delivered to the calling process in seconds seconds."*? Is there something else you are asking?

Comment: Interrupts are for hardware. The OS is sending a signal.

Answer (score 2):

On x86 and x86_64, the kernel gets the time from an IRQ timer, and when the IRQ time is the original time plus 120 seconds, the kernel sends `SIGALRM` to your application.

I have no idea how the IRQ timer itself works though; you'd probably get a better answer about that on a hardware site.